# Find element by part of id-selenium web driver

Tags: jquery, css, selenium

Hi guys I have element which has these atr :

```
<input type="text" class="id-element clearable ui-input-text ui-body-a" data-mini="true" maxlength="50" id="bec563ae2-AccountUser_Name">
```

And I want it find by `ID`, but the part of `id=bec563ae2-` is automatic generated for every single user.
Then using will don´t work:

```
IWebElement profilUser = driverGC.FindElement(By.Id("id"));
```

Yep there is still way to find it by `ClassName`(but it doesn´t work correctly here) or by `CssSelector`, but if I try to find it by `CssSelector`, I will get into some part of this element, but I will not be able to work with it(filling name).

Ok I tried this one, but unsuccessfully :

```
IWebElement profilUserName = driverGC.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ui-page-active .msls-dialog-inner-frame .msls-tab-content .msls-first-row .msls-presenter-content .div:nth-child(1)"));
profilUserName.SendKeys("Paul");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for an element with an ID that ends with a specific string:
Here is how to do it using css selector

```
driverGC.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[id$='AccountUser_Name']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CssSelector you have to make sure there are no spaces in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can still use XPath for locating the element.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath expression"))
```